# Getting explicit BaseStyle or DefaultBaseStyle settings

Tags: gui-construction

Is there a way of making more similar the appearance of `TogglerBar` and `Toggler` controls that can sometimes appear quite different:

```
TogglerBar[{1}, {1, 2}]
```

[image: TogggleBar1]

```
TogglerBar[{1}, {1}]
```

[image: ToggleBar2]

```
Toggler[1, {1, 2}]
```

[image]

- presumably most readily by accessing corresponding `BaseStyle`/`DefaultBaseStyle` settings?